# What does a “rolling period” mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does a “rolling period” mean here?

Ukrainian citizens entering the country with a biometric passport may stay in Hungary without a visa for a maximum period of 90 days (within any 180-day rolling period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the scenario where a Ukrainian visitor visits Hungary, without a visa, as follows:

1. Jan 02 thru Apr 01 (90 days): not in Hungary
2. Apr 02 thru Jun 30 (90 days): **in Hungary**
3. Jul 01 thru Sep 28 (90 days): **in Hungary**
4. Sep 29 thru Dec 27 (90 days): not in Hungary

That is, they are in Hungary for two back-to-back 90-day stays -- periods #2 and #3 in the above list; a total of 180 days.

Now notice that in the first half of the year (strictly, periods #1 and #2: January 2nd thru June 30th) they are in Hungary for only 90 days in that 180 day period.
Similarly, in the second half of the year (strictly, periods #3 and #4: July 1st through December 27th) they are also in Hungary for only 90 days in *that* 180 day period.

So without the "rolling" caveat, the visitor might think that they have obeyed the 90-in-180-day without-a-visa rule. But of course, that would only be the case if we considered only those two *specific* 180-day periods I just mentioned.

Therefore, the "rolling" is added to make it absolutely clear that *all* periods of 180-days need to be considered; not just the two half-years. That is, the only-90-in-180 rule must be satisfied for the 180-day period starting on January 1st, *and* the one starting on January 2nd, *and* the one starting on January 3rd, and so on. In other words, the starting date for the 180-day period "rolls" forward.

And with that understood, then the scenario I described, with two back-to-back 90-day periods, is *not* permitted by the without-a-visa rule.

It is a feature/bug (depending on your point of view) of this approach, that you could have two people visiting Hungary for a total of 180 days each in a single calendar year, but where one violates the rule and the other -- for example, by visiting for one 90-day block starting on January 2nd, and the other starting on July 1st (and leaving Hungary in the intervening period). In other words, while the above travel itinerary would not be allowed, the following would:

1. Jan 02 thru Apr 01 (90 days): **in Hungary**
2. Apr 02 thru Jun 30 (90 days): not in Hungary
3. Jul 01 thru Sep 28 (90 days): **in Hungary**
4. Sep 29 thru Dec 27 (90 days): not in Hungary

And that's despite the fact that both itineraries involve the same amount of time in Hungary. Why they are using 90-in-180 instead of 180-in-360 that is often used for tax residency purposes, I've no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you pick any date on a calendar, and another date 180 days ahead, the total number of days in that period you are allowed to be in the country is 90.

The 'rolling period' is any period of 180 days.

I don't know if the entry conditions allow multiple entry and exit. But suppose you have been in the country for 90 days, you must leave and you will need to wait another 90 days before you can enter again.

Comment: Right, in other words the 180 days are not defined on a calendar as being from one specific day to another.